# Opening generated PDF after saving it in browser

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I had a method to populate PDF in browsers. It can have PDF be shown in the browsers perfectly. However after I clicked "SAVE" bottom, and open the downloaded file from my local, it shows

> "Adobe Reader could not open 'xxx.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

Below is my code

```
public static void PopulatePDF(byte[] PDFcontents)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=xxx.pdf");
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", PDFcontents.Length.ToString());
    response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

    response.OutputStream.Write(PDFcontents,0,contents.PDFcontents);
    response.BufferOutput = true;
    response.Buffer = true;

    response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;

    response.BinaryWrite(PDFcontents);

    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
```

The method did pass data (`byte[2100217]`) and display the pdf in the browser. But the tricky part is that it couldn't be opened from the downloaded file at local after "Save" was used.

Not sure what happened in between. Is this due to the version of Adobe Reader I'm using? It's Adobe Reader XI (version 11.0.10).

Comment: did you compare the original v.s what got saved? e.g. same number of bytes in both?

Comment: Yes I did. There are in the same size. The PDFcontents is {byte[2100217]}; the saved file xxx.pdf is 2.00MB (2,100,217 btyes)

Comment: Actually the "Size on disk" shows 2.00MB (2,101,248 bytes) ; "Size" shows 2.00MB (2,100,217bytes)